# IIS 7.5 URL rewrite based on domain name

Tags: asp.net, tomcat, iis, iis-7

I'm currently using IIS 7.5 to both host ASP pages and as a bridge to a tomcat server setup to host JasperReports.  I've been trying to figure out how to host both of these services with 1 IP and one IIS server.

**What it should do**

**1)** When the account managers visit `admin.mycompany.com`, I'd like to display the ASP pages in IIS. under the domain `admin.mycompany.com`

**2)** When the account managers visits `reports.mycompany.com`, IIS should act as a bridge to the tomcat server and display the tomcat pages under `reports.mycompany.com`

**Restrictions**

**1)** Our hosting provider refuses to give us a 2nd IP, and

**2)** I'd prefer not to install Apache, which can easily do this with virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be resolve with https://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server

I copied vdboor's answer here for reference:

For IIS 7.5, Microsoft provides official modules for this!

```
URL Rewrite: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite
Reverse proxy: http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting
```

In the site settings, you'll get an "URL Rewrite" icon.

```
Open it
right click on the "inbound rules list"
Select "Add Rule(s)"
Choose "Reverse proxy"
```

In this dialog you can enter the hostname + port to forward to. After adding the rule, opening the edit dialog offers more customizations.

Answer (score 0):

the reverse proxy template is not available at the server level.
- so you need to go to the site level, and then click the 'URL rewrite' icon to be able to use this template.
http://forums.iis.net/t/1183318.aspx